# Error with Nested ASP.NEt Repeaters and Database Table

Tags: dataset, nested-repeater

I'm having some dramas with Nested Repeaters in ASP.NET using VB.

I have search through this and a few other forums but cannot work out my code problem. All of the other examples ive found have been using an XML Datasource, or using multiple tables within a dataset. My Dataset only contains 1 table with all the necessary fields.

I essentially want to create an Event Calendar... eg

```
-September
      Event 1
      Event 2
-October
      Event 3
-November
      Event 4
      Event 5
      Event 6
```

All of the info is stored in 1 Table in my Database.

My Code so Far...

aspx

```
<asp:repeater id="rptCalendar" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Month")%>
        <asp:repeater id="NestedRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventName")%>
                <br>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub rptCalendar_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptCalendar.ItemDataBound
    Dim dv As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim nestedrepeater As Repeater = e.Item.FindControl("NestedRepeater")
        Dim drv As DataRowView = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
        nestedrepeater.DataSource = drv.CreateChildView("EventName")
        nestedrepeater.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

My Page_Load event just loads the entire table into a dataset called dsEvents and binds it. The Database looks like this.

```
-Events
    EventID
    EventName
    EventDate
    Month
    Day
```

The error message im getting is 
"The relation is not parented to the table to which this DataView points."

I haven't worked with Nested Repeaters before so not too sure what im doing wrong.

Comment: Doesn't `CreateChildView` operate on a parent/child relationship between *two* tables in the data?  If you have only *one* table as you say, how do you expect this to work?  What is the "child view" you're trying to create?

Comment: I did try it without the CreateChildView and it brought up another error

DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'EventName'.

As I havent used NestedRepeaters before i assumed the CreateChildView was needed.

Comment: A) You tried *what*?  B) *What* was the error?  You certainly shouldn't be randomly trying things.  What are you actually attempting to *do* here?  According to your question you have *one* table, so logically how can you even populate nested repeaters with data?  Aside from the implementation details of doing so, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Apologies, i accidentally hit the enter key and it posted the comment. I have edited the comment to include answers to the questions.
The reason why i am looking into Nested Repeaters is that I do not know how many events there are per month, I need to have the Month Displayed, but not if the following 3 events are in the same month.

This seemed to be the most popular solution, plus I can see the use for it with other pages on the site. However if there is a better solution im all ears.

Comment: The problem you're facing isn't really a matter of nested repeaters, it's a matter of incorrectly modeled data.  Since you only have one table you can't derive a related table from a column on that table.  You basically need to create *two* tables which relate to one another based on how you're trying to view the data.  Note that you don't necessarily need to use `DataTable`s for this, you can for example loop through your records and build custom objects which represent your data.  Then bind the repeaters to those objects.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... I was under the impression that this sort of thing would be a bit more straight forward than it looks... Am i going about it the wrong way? Would there be a better solution to achieve what i'm after?

Comment: Well, essentially you need to transform your data into two relational elements. There are many ways to go about that. If you don't want to change the physical database structure then I would recommend creating custom objects in code which represent those elements. There could be a parent object which has a property that is a list of child objects. You'd loop through the data, building the parent and child objects (likely a nested loop of some sort) and then bind the repeater to the list of parent objects. The nested repeater would bind to each parent object's list of child objects.